# Does a kosher pot become non-kosher after you kasher utensils in it?

Tags: halacha, kashering-kosherization

I'm kashering a number of non-kosher, metal utensil with a kosher pot. If heat is a mechanism through which things can become non-kosher, does kashering my utensils in the pot (via Hagalah) make my pot non-kosher? If not, why doesn't the treyf-ness transfer?

Comment: I assume the vessels are more than a day old? In that case there is no treif left to transfer. It all tastes bad by then.

Comment: Interesting...I thought the reason for the hagalah in the first place was to remove the treif from the vessel. If there is no treif left, why do we do hagalah?

Comment: So we don't come to use a less than day old pot.

Comment: Possible answer here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/71034/1516

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concern is that the non-kosher taste reenters the utensils or enteres the pot.   If you are concerned about this (despite the valid comment above about a day-old taste being rotten), put soap in the water before you put the non-kosher utensils in the pot. That way, any non-kosher taste mixes immediately with the soapy water.  That renders any such taste non-edible, which means it is not food, which means it is no longer non-kosher and can not make the pot (or anything else) non-kosher.  This works also if the non-kosher utensils have been used within the past day.  As I understand it, caterers use this approach often.  (Perhaps there are caterers reading this who might chime in.)

Answer (score 2):

If it's past a day, I believe the kashering pot is fine without soap. If the treife utensils were used within a day, that is a different story.There are some caterers who have boiled treife tensils in a toxic solution before kashering them. However, Rav Blumenkranz zt"l writes in his pesach book that this should not be relied upon.

Comment: Is Rav Blumenkranz' comment on toxic solution specific to Pesach or meant to apply year-round?

Comment: Rav Blumenkranz zt"l wrote his comments regarding caterers whom have kashered treife facilities for kosher events.